# Finding the number of row with the smallest sum of powers, C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I have an array, in which I need to find the number of row, which has the smallest sum of powers. Consider the example array:

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

The first row, (index = 0), the sum of powers is equal to 3 (1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 = 3).

The second row, (index = 1), the sum of powers is equal to 12 (2^2 + 2^2 + 2^2 = 12).

The third row, (index = 2), the sum of powers is equal to 27 (3^2 + 3^2 + 3^2 = 27).

But my program shows the wrong result - instead of index `0`, it shows index `2`. What is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int ** alloc(int n, int m)
{
    int **array, i;

    array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * m);

    return array;
}

void show(int **array, int n, int m)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void fill(int **array, int n, int m, int x)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = x;
        }
    }
}

void dealloc(int **array, int n, int m)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        free(array[i]);
    free(array);
}

int smallest_powers_sum(int **array, int n, int m)
{
    int sum = 0, minsum = 0, i, j, minindex = -1;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        minsum = sum;
        sum = 0;

        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            sum += pow(array[i][j], 2);
        }

        if(minsum <= sum)
            minindex = i;

        printf("sum = %d, minsum = %d, minindex = %d\n", sum, minsum, minindex);
    }

    return minindex;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int **array, n1 = 3, m1 = 3;

    array = alloc(n1, m1);
    fill(array, n1, m1, 1);

    array[0][0] = 1;
    array[0][1] = 1;
    array[0][2] = 1;

    array[1][0] = 2;
    array[1][1] = 2;
    array[1][2] = 2;

    array[2][0] = 3;
    array[2][1] = 3;
    array[2][2] = 3;


    int sum = smallest_powers_sum(array, n1, m1);
    printf("index = %d\n", sum);

    dealloc(array, n1, m1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant this:

```
     if(sum <= minsum ){
         minindex = i;
         minsum = sum;
     }
```

Also, initially assign integer_max to `minsum`.

Here's the code:

```
int smallest_powers_sum(int **array, int n, int m)
{
    int sum = 0, minsum = 1000000, i, j, minindex = -1;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {

        sum = 0;

        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            sum += pow(array[i][j], 2);
        }

        if(sum <= minsum ){
         minindex = i;
         minsum = sum;
     }

        printf("sum = %d, minsum = %d, minindex = %d\n", sum, minsum, minindex);
    }

    return minindex;
}
```

Comment: It did not help, because for the array `1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 2` it shows index `2`: http://pastie.org/private/nyhnpig0m8l80laoefg

Answer (score 0):

This line kills all your "memory" of previous rows:

```
minsum = sum;
```

You should only update `minsum` together with updating `minindex`.

Also your condition for updating `minindex` seems to be the wrong way around.

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way to do (although a bare-bones version):

```
#define NROWS 3
#define NCOLS 3

int *getminrow(int *p, int n)
{
        int minval = *p;
        int *minaddr = p;

        while (n >= 1) {
                if (*p < minval) {
                        minval = *p;
                        minaddr = p;
                }
                n--;
                p++;
        }

        return minaddr;
}


int sumrow(int *p, int n)
{
        int sum = 0;
        while (n >= 1) {
                sum += (*p);
                n--;
                p++;
        }

        return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
        int *array = malloc(NROWS * NCOLS);
        int listsum[NROWS];
        int i, j;

        array[0 * NROWS + 0] = 1;
        array[0 * NROWS + 1] = 1;
        array[0 * NROWS + 2] = 1;

        array[1 * NROWS + 0] = 2;
        array[1 * NROWS + 1] = 2;
        array[1 * NROWS + 2] = 2;

        array[2 * NROWS + 0] = 3;
        array[2 * NROWS + 1] = 3;
        array[2 * NROWS + 2] = 3;

        for (i = 0; i < NROWS; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < NCOLS; j++) {
                        array[i * NROWS + j] = pow(array[i * NROWS + j], 2);
                }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < NROWS; i++) 
                listsum[i] = sumrow(&array[i], NCOLS);

        printf("Min row: %d\n", getminrow(listsum, NROWS) - listsum);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some problem in your logic. First "if(minisum<=sum)". It must be "if(sum<=minisum)". Second, if you're just using coding like that, then the condition will be considered only condition i and i-1. So, my advice to change the syntax "if(minisum<=sum)" with the following script. (There are new variables that I call minisumtemp).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int ** alloc(int n, int m)
{
    int **array, i;

    array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * m);

    return array;
}

void show(int **array, int n, int m)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void fill(int **array, int n, int m, int x)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = x;
        }
    }
}

void dealloc(int **array, int n, int m)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        free(array[i]);
    free(array);
}

int smallest_powers_sum(int **array, int n, int m)
{
    //int sum = 0, minsum = 0, i, j, minindex = -1;
    int sum = 0, minsum = 0, i, j, minindex = 0, minsumtemp; // add new variable : minsumtemp

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        minsum = sum;
        sum = 0;

        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            sum += pow(array[i][j], 2);
        }

        //if(minsum <= sum)   this the problem
         //   minindex = i;
        if (i==0) minsumtemp = sum; // initialized first value for minsumtep
        if (sum<=minsumtemp)
        {
            minindex = i;
            minsumtemp = sum;
        }

        printf("sum = %d, minsum = %d, minindex = %d\n", sum, minsum, minindex);
    }

    return minindex;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int **array, n1 = 3, m1 = 3;

    array = alloc(n1, m1);
    fill(array, n1, m1, 1);

    array[0][0] = 1;
    array[0][1] = 1;
    array[0][2] = 1;

    array[1][0] = 2;
    array[1][1] = 2;
    array[1][2] = 2;

    array[2][0] = 3;
    array[2][1] = 3;
    array[2][2] = 3;


    int sum = smallest_powers_sum(array, n1, m1);
    printf("index = %d\n", sum);

    dealloc(array, n1, m1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wkwkwkwk... I apologize for my poor English language skills. I just want to help to solve the problem. (and about the syntax,, thanks for the correction)

Comment: `I apologize for my poor English language skills.` don't - it isn't anybody's fault not to be a "native speaker" (`wkwkwkwk`&profile image: near Indonesia?). Just make your computer help you (use a spelling checker), and try to make your contributions easy to understand. (_Not_ saying you have done bad in that regard.)